# How can I boot Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from the USB port?

Tags: boot

I got ubuntu desktop. I want to test it from the USB port on my HP desktop. The download file was ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso. I transferred this file to the flash drive on my USB port.  When I try to boot from this file I get "BOOTMGR is missing". Any idea why I can't boot from this file?

Comment: "bought"? Ubuntu is free. Where did you get it from?

Comment: You also can't just copy an ISO or the contents of the ISO to the USB. That won't work. You need to actually burn it, using a utility, such as [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Comment: @Zacharee1 In places with slow or unreliable Internet service, it is common for people to provide discs of Ubuntu or other systems, and charge for the service. Nothing wrong with that. Ubuntu is free as in "free speech", not necessarily "free beer".

Comment: And yes, you can copy an ISO onto USB media.

Comment: @fkraiem I'm fairly certain that redistribution still needs to be authorized, and since when can you put an ISO onto a USB and have it be bootable?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Of course redistribution needs to be authorised, and for the software contained in Ubuntu, the license allows this. If it didn't, you could not obtain Ubuntu from anywhere, as Ubuntu contains software written by many people, most of whom are not affiliated with Ubuntu in any way. And the Ubuntu ISOs have allowed booting from USB for several years now. Just try it: `sudo dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdX`.

Comment: @fkraiem That's not what it appears this person has done. I believe they have either copied the ISO file itself, note the contents, to the USB; or dragged and dropped the contents into the USB. Neither of these works. The fact that they also say "the download file" makes me think it was downloaded, not copied from a CD. (An Ubuntu CD wouldn't have just an ISO file on it, it would have the contents.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot boot from an iso placed on media, it has to be written to it. You're comparatively trying to utilize files from an archive without extracting first. [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) is a user friendly tool to help write the image to portable media. After installing, insert your USB drive and follow the 1-2-3 design and allow several minutes for writing. Afterwards, place the USB in the desired computer and change the boot order to boot from USB. If that option is not available you must enable booting from USB from your BIOS. During this process you shouldn't see `BOOTMGR is missing`. Bootmgr is the Windows bootloader and will not play a part in the operation. You should be running Trusty Tahr in no time.